# Applying Zorn's lemma to Cantor set

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, cantor-set

Let $C_n$ be the set obtained in the $n$-th step for constructing the Cantor set. It is not hard to see that $C_i \subseteq C_j$ if $i>j$ and we know that the Cantor set is $\cap_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n$.
However, recently, while doing some exercise concerning number theory, I noticed that we may apply Zorn's lemma to $C_n$. Obviously, each $C_n$ is non-empty and is a subset of $[0,1]$, thus there is a partial order defined by inclusion. If we consider the chain
$$C_0 \supseteq C_1 \supseteq ...\supseteq C_n \supseteq ...$$
By Zorn's lemma, it seems to me that this becomes stationary after $n$ steps(everything is trivially lower-bounded by $\varnothing$), which contradicts what we know about Cantor set.  Could anyone tell me where I have made a mistake?

Comment: I believe you mean $$C_j \subseteq C_i$$

Comment: Do you also believe that there is a largest natural number? We can certainly apply Zorn's lemma to $0<1<2<\dots<n<\dots$ by the same logic.

Comment: @Carlyle Yes, thanks for reminding me of this. I have just corrected it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think $0<1<2<...<n<...$ is a good counter-examples since it is not upper-bounded and Zorn's lemma requires a such bound.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am not sure I understand the connection between your comment and the error made in OP's reasoning, it seems you are highlighting the fact that every chain needs an upper bound (not just finite chains) whereas OP seems to be completely misinterpreting the statement of Zorn's lemma (or perhaps I am completely misinterpreting their question)

Comment: @RHspqr why does Zorn say it stabilizes? That partial order has a minimal element, the empty set. That’s all Zorn says.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the conclusion that "this becomes stationary after $n$ steps", it is not clear how you reached this conclusion

Comment: @Carlyle Sure. By Zorn's lemma, there should be a maximal element for a chain if it is bounded by some element, meaning there exists $C_n$ such that $C_{n+k}=C_n, \forall k>0$. I notice that the expression on Wikipedia is a bit different, but I'm not sure if this is the problem, since it's the standard statement in our algebra course.

Comment: @RHspqr Consider the linear order of $\mathbb N\cup \{\infty\}.$ It would seem by your logic, $\mathbb N $ should have a greatest element. All Zorn (in the formulation that if every linearly ordered subset has an upper bound, then the poset has a maximal element) says here is that the ordering has a maximal element, and it does... $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to note that you are working with a slightly different version, with "maximal" and "upper" replaced by "minimal" and "lower" respectively. Keeping that in mind, your problem arose because you have not made it completely clear what the relevant poset is. If the poset is $$\{C_0,C_1,C_2,...\}$$ with inclusion, then Zorn's lemma tells us nothing, since the chain $$\{C_0,C_1,C_2...\}$$ has no lower bound in this poset.

If the poset is $$P([0,1])$$
Then indeed Zorn's lemma guarantees that there is a minimal element, but this is trivial since $$\emptyset\in P([0,1])$$

I suspect that it is one of these that you intended, if not, once you explicitly write down the poset, and actually verify that the conditions of the lemma hold, then all confusion will disappear